# Consolidate Columns of Text?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to VBA and I've run across something I've been unable to figure out: I have a list of items in column A and the corresponding locations in column B. There are many duplicate items in column A and I am trying to find a way to consolidate this spreadsheet so there are no duplicate items in A and all the locations that each item is in a single column B cell and are separated by `", "`. i.e. if `A2=A3=A11` I would want the output to be the text of A2 in column A and:

`=B2 & ", " & B3 & ", " & B11`

in Column B. (I was hoping to post a picture to make this more clear but don't have that right since I'm new here, let me know if I wasn't clear about something.
Any pointers in the right direction to get me started on this would be much appreciated-thanks in advance!

Comment: use [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) object to store column A values in its keys and gathering column B values in corresponding items

Comment: another good reference for [Dictionary](https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub repeat()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, columnB As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(1, 100)
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 100), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 100).End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 100).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("A:B").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=ws.Cells(i, 100)
    For Each Bcell In ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    columnB = columnB & ", " & Bcell
    Next Bcell
    For Each Acell In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Acell.Value = Acell.Value & columnB
    Next Acell
    columnB = ""
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, I get a "Method 'Remove Duplicates' of Object 'Range'" error message that I've been unable to resolve after playing around with the Remove Duplicates line for a while. Any ideas, is it running smoothly for you?

Comment: Try by removing this: (Columns:=1) from the removeduplicates line.